# ¿Se utiliza o conoce la palabra "sinsorgo" en Murcia?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, españa

Hace algún tiempo me sorprendió encontrar la palabra *sinsorgo* en el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XzT2erQ) pero aún me extrañó más los lugares donde se usa (según el diccionario):

> Del vasco *zenzurgue.*
>   1. adj. *Ál., Mur.* y *Vizc*. Dicho de una persona: Insustancial y de poca formalidad. U. t. c. s.

En Araba y Bizkaia, hasta aquí todo normal ya que es una palabra que viene del euskera pero sorprendentemente también aparece Murcia, un lugar en la otra punta de la península. ¿Realmente se usa allí? ¿Cómo llegó?

La etimología tampoco la veo muy clara, no se muy bien de donde sacan la palabra *zenzurgue* pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Como añadido, también se usa en Aragón.

Comment: @FGSUZ Interesante, pensaba que era algo bastante local, de la zona de Bilbao sobretodo ya que ni siquiera se usa en todo el País Vasco.

Comment: Para evitar confusiones, aclarar que el DRAE indica que se usa enÁlava, Murcia y Vizcaya. *Araba* y *Bizkaia* son los otros nombres oficiales de Álava y Vizcaya

Comment: Ahora los nombres oficiales son Araba/Álava, Gipuzkoa y Bizkaia. Álava es la única provincia que mantiene las dos formas.

Comment: Que interesante - no lo sabía. Supongo que entonces la RAE tendrá que cambiar la definición de **sinsorgo, ga** a :
Del **vascuence** *zenzurgue*. 1. adj. **Ál./Ar., Mur. y Bizk.** Dicho de una persona: Insustancial y de poca formalidad

Comment: A lo que dice @FGSUZ añado que yo siempre he oído esa palabra como *sinsorga*, tanto para el masculino como para el femenino. Así, puedo decir de un hombre que *es un sinsorga*.

Comment: ¿Dónde se usa de esa forma @Gorpik ?

Comment: @blonfu En Aragón, como decía FGSUZ. Al menos, en el Bajo Aragón; ahora mismo no te puedo asegurar que se utilice de forma habitual en toda la región.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lo primero, comentar que conozco a mucha gente de Murcia, y a pesar de ello no he escuchado nunca tal palabra.

Buscando en Google `sinsorgo murcia` lo único que se encuentra, al menos entre las tres primeras páginas de resultados -que ya es decir-, son mensajes en foros y entradas de *blog* de gente que **no** es de la Región (esto se comprueba fácilmente mediante lo que dicen en otros mensajes o entradas) y que, en muchos casos, se limitan a repetir lo que dice el DLE.

Los únicos dos resultados que ofrecen algo de interés, son dos coincidencias de (cómo no) Google Books:

- En [*Léxico de la Región Prebética: límites del lenguaje andaluz y murciano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=yYkoCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA142&dq=sinsorgo%20murcia&hl=es&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=sinsorgo%20murcia&f=false) (Alejandro Faustino Idáñez de Aguilar, ed. Editum. Ediciones de la Universidad de Murcia, 2015), encontramos:

  > En el *DRAE* ***sinsorgo*** "persona insustancial y de poca formalidad" que localiza en Álava, Vizcaya y Murcia. (...) en Murcia Alberto Sevilla recoge ***sinsorga*** "persona indiferente, apática, insustancial" *(VM)*. García Soriano registra ***sinsorgo/ga*** "dícese de la persona insustancial y de poca formalidad" *(VDM)*, y *sinsato* "insensato, paralizado" *(DPNT)*. *Sonsano* "ignorante o de poca lucidez" *(VNA)* y las variantes *sonsanico*, *sonsarrón*, *soscarra* "torpe o bobo" en la zona de Segura y Yeste, y también *soscarrón* o *soscarra(d)o*. En la zona de Caravaca *sonso/sa* "zonzo, soso, tonto fingido para conseguir su propósito" *(VDM)* y las variantes *sonsano* y *sónsolo*.

  Aquí hace referencia a *sinsorga*, en femenino, y enumera una serie de palabras relacionadas. Algunas de estas sí que las he oído alguna vez; concretamente: *sonsarrón*, *sonso/sa* y *sónsolis* (que no está recogida, pero entiendo que es variación de *sónsolo*).
- Por otra parte, *[Vocabulario murciano](https://books.google.es/books?id=pwgWAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA172&ots=J0mDCStwyw&dq=sinsorga%20murcia&hl=es&pg=PA172#v=onepage&q=sinsorga%20murcia&f=false)* (Alberto Sevilla, 1919) es más directo:

  > **Sinsorga.** Mujer indiferente, apática, insustancial.

  Alberto Sevilla fue, entre otras cosas, un escritor y periodista murciano que publicó [varios libros [PDF]](http://www.regmurcia.com/docs/murgetana/N077/N077_001.pdf) a principios del s. XX.
- Y, por no dejar fuera a la otra fuente mencionada, si buscamos directamente en Google Books podemos encontrar *[Vocabulario del dialecto murciano](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&id=rSRKAAAAYAAJ&dq=vocabulario%20murcia%20soriano&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=sinsorgo)* (Justo García Soriano, 1932), donde efectivamente se puede leer también:

  > **sinsorgo, ga.** adj. Dícese de la persona insubstancial y de poca formalidad. (Us. t. en Vizc.)

  Aquí se recoge tanto en masculino como en femenino, y ya se indica su uso común con Vizcaya.

En [otros recopilatorios](http://www.laopiniondemurcia.es/murcia/2017/06/17/tiricia-cascarujas-palabros/838387.html) de [vocabulario murciano](https://www.descubriendomurcia.com/diccionario-murciano/), algo [menos académicos](https://www.saberespractico.com/curiosidades/diccionario-murciano-espanol-por-orden-alfabetico/), no aparece la palabra.

Ante las evidencias anteriores, no queda sino aceptar que *en algún momento* **sinsorgo/a** ha sido vocablo del habla murciana, aún cuando su uso hoy en día sea mínimo.

---

Sobre cómo llegó la palabra desde aquellos lares a estos... Es casi imposible saberlo.

- En CORDE hay muy pocos resultados: un libreto de 1926 ambientado en algún lugar del País Vasco, una obra de autor vasco, y una mención en otra obra de Pío Baroja: *"(...) sinsorgo, como dicen en Bilbao."*.
- El CREA es menos generoso aún, arrojando un único resultado procedente de una obra de teatro de Antonio Gala ambientada "en un pueblo de la España rural".
- [Google NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sinsorga&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csinsorga%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csinsorga%3B%2Cc1) no muestra ningún resultado en absoluto anterior a los dos diccionarios murcianos de 1919 y 1932 (ni posterior, de hecho, hasta 1960).

Es decir, que la palabra no es solo que hoy día sea prácticamente desconocida, es que hace casi un siglo tampoco la usaba casi nadie. Por tanto, complicado saber cómo pasó una palabra de un sitio a otro, sin fuentes sobre las que se pueda trazar su historia.

Answer (score 1):

Zentzuge es "zentzu gabe", "sin conocimiento". La etimologia "zentzurge" es de R. M. Azkue.  Sin embargo, no creo que existe esa variante.

En el castellano del País Vasco, se emplea con parecido significado, "sin fuste", (algo que carece del material del que se supone estar hecho el fuste, es decir, la madera) también con sentido de insustancial.

Por ello, yo creo que "sinsorgo", podría ser simplemente eso, "*un pan*", "sin sorgo".